# How to make a player in a 2D game in Unity bounce off ground based on the angle he is touching the collider of the ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I want the player to bounce off the ground only when he touches it from the side, so that the player does not get stuck on the collision and does not bounce off when he stands on top of ground. The player uses the Box Collider 2D and the ground uses the Tilemap Collider 2D and the Composite Collider 2D.

I tried using Physics Material 2D, however it causes the player to bounce on all sides.
In order to identify where the player contacted the ground and whether that point is normal to Vector2, I tried using OnCollisionEnter2D and GetContact.
But, it still didn't turn out well.
That script looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BouncyGround : MonoBehaviour {
    public float bounceForce = 10f;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            Vector2 normal = collision.GetContact(0).point;
            if (Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Dot(normal, Vector2.up)) < 0.1f) {
                Vector2 direction = new Vector2(collision.transform.position.x, collision.transform.position.y)
                    - collision.contacts[0].point;
                direction.Normalize();
                collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * bounceForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. For anyone wondering, i use platform effector2d, uncheked use one way option and clicked used by effector on composite collider 2d